# Is this question about spell effects persisting after death a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

Candidate for closure: [Effect lasts until end of dead creature’s next turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179908/62294)

Dupe target: [Do your spells end when you die?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65305/do-your-spells-end-when-you-die)

Should this question be closed as a duplicate of the proposed dupe target?

Comment: Just as a nudge/preference; it might be fruitful for discussions like this to at minimum explain why they as asked (as full meta questions). Normally votes or comments should be sufficient to resolve it and having every disagreement escalated to meta might get tiring.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments on the mainsite question. Can retrieve them if anyone would like, but I don't think there's anything there that isn't covered here.

Answer (score 2):

### Half of it is

So I closed it originally, and didn't see the responses until now. The crux here, I think, is – let's call it an oddity of grammar – where the question is actually two questions but doesn't look like it (and probably wouldn't need separation normally). Doing the full analysis:

> is the spell ended when they die or does it continue until when their turn would have occurred?

Looks like it's simply asking which of these is the correct outcome/way it works (A or B). We have a question (the current target) which answers not A, and so one would assume B to be the case. Except there's more to B (it's treading into undefined rules for one), so it at least warrants a separate answer.

There are two ways here, the natural route if the querent had responded would be for them to edit in that information and focus the question to the novel case (ie. edit it to ask how B works). We could do that for them, or we could have answers cover that point (say by linking to the current target) and then answer for how B works (or whether it has workings in the rule if need be).

I suggest we go with the latter.

Comment: Sounds like an issue of needs focus or needs details then?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Not really. The only (close worthy) issue with the question was the overlap in scope with another question, which is just something that happens from time to time.

Comment: That is one of the reasons we like questions to show research, such as other questions on related topics and why they don't answer the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I dont really get it but I’ll unhammer it for now. I’ll come back later and reevaluate it.

Comment: The issue with assuming it is a duplicate is that this isn't a clear case covered in the 'duplicate' question, this is asking about a specific edge case. If we get into the habit of closing edge cases as duplicates of questions which ask about the common case, then we are effectively saying that all answers need to cover every edge case, which is unreasonable.

Comment: @SeriousBri Well, I missed the edge case when I originally closed it, but left a comment encouraging any aspects to make it unique be pointed out (as a comment or edit). At that point we'd have figured out what to do. That's our normal processes working as intended.  Where to cover edge cases is something we have to figure out as site curators, there's no hard line between updating the master and having a separate question. For this case I'm certainly in favour of having a separate though

Comment: This isn’t just an edge case of the other question, though - while the example is a spell, the question as phrased is about magical (and possibly other) effects in general, which to my mind makes it broader as it’s not just about spells. So it would be better rephrased as: “If a character dies, when do their spells and effects end if they normally last until their next turn?”

Answer (score 1):

### It is not a duplicate, but it could use some improvements

The core of the newer question is "If an effect lasts until a creature's "next turn", but that creature dies before they get a next turn, when does the effect end?". The older question does not contain an answer to this new question.

There are two parts of the new question that make it seem more like a duplicate, however I don't believe either of them actually cause it to be even a partial duplicate. These are:

1. The asker chose a hypothetical where the "effect" is a spell and the "creature" is the caster of that spell. This situation has some overlap with the dupe target, but even then the dupe target doesn't contain an answer.
2. The asker provided two possibilities for answers, and one of them is (probably) ruled out by the dupe target. That makes the other possibility seem like a trivial answer, but the correct answer could be something else entirely.

I also see two ways to improve the question, though they should not be interpreted as the only possible ways to improve the question, nor are they necessarily exclusive.

1. The original asker can update the question with more detail about the specific situation they had in mind, particularly the exact spell (Booming Blade is in there now, but it was not added by the asker). This could clarify that the more specific situation is indeed covered by an existing question, or more clearly show ways it is not covered.
2. The question could be rephrased to reduce the confusion without requiring additional information from the asker. For example, by breaking it into a more structured form with multiple sentences and possibly paragraphs, or by changing the end to something like "this prior question indicates that it won't end immediately from the caster's death, but would it become a permanent effect unless the caster is Raised to start taking turns again, or something else?"